# Failed to create invoice for orders having bundle product with fixed pricing

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, invoice

I have configured a Bundle products comprised of Virtul & Simple products and using fixed pricing for each bundle option.

When trying to create order at checkout and creating invoice behind the scene, it is throwing error

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Return value of Magento\InventorySourceSelection\Model\Request\InventoryRequest::getItems() must be of the type array, null returned in /www/vendor/magento/module-inventory-source-selection/Model/Request/InventoryRequest.php:102

I was looking for the solution and found out that this is a bug in Magento 2.3 reported at https://github.com/magento/inventory/issues/3172

The above reported issue is still not resolved by Magento. Is there anyone else who faced such issue? Looking for some suggestions here about how to handle this issue using Magento 2.3

P.S I am trying to create invoice immediately after the transaction is authorized i.e. when customer palces order from checkout via Stripe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I resolved this issue by overriding the class

> Magento\InventorySourceSelection\Model\Request\InventoryRequest.php

and then redefined below method

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function getItems(): array
{
    /**
        Return array() if value is NULL 
    */
    if(empty($this->items))
    {
        return array();
    }

    return $this->items;
}
```

So now `getItems()` will return `array()` if the value of `$items` is `NULL`. And will resolve this problem.

Further, it seems like this issue was to be fixed by Magento team in 2.3 as you can see a note in `Magento\InventorySourceSelection\Model\Request\InventoryRequest at Line: 76` where the `$items` is defined. It says:

> //TODO: Temporary fix for resolving issue with webApi (https://github.com/magento-engcom/msi/issues/1524)